Beam splitter using a lazer to do the splitting
My title may be misleading, and my question is definatly amateur. I would like to split a beam of light, with a second beam. I suspect this may not be possible (or only possible with large amounts of energy expended by the second "splitter" beam). I'm having trouble finding layman terms explaining why. Google keeps trying to sell me an optical beam splitter. Physics.stackexchange keeps telling me about the double slit experiment.
My goal with the idea is to take a radiant heater as the source light, and use a second lazer to "modulate" or "control" the radiation that makes it past the second lazer and ultimatly heats a surface.
I'm sure this can be easily understood by many people who are much more knowledgeble then me, but I am looking for a simpleton explanation, if possible.
I'll try to explain the question in another way. A lazer shines from the north to the south. 100% goes to the southern surface. A second lazer intersects from east to west. Is there a way for the second beam to interfer so that only 50% of the source north lazer arrives at the south surface? Irregardless of the distance to the southern surface (I'm not looking to create an interferance pattern at a specific distance; I'd like to throw away some of the source light in another direction)?

No it is not possible.  Photons/light just cross each other like water waves or sound waves can cross each other.  With water waves we can see the superposition where they cross and after they cross they emerge as if nothing happened.  Light can we considered as waves in the EM field ... but we can never observe the superpositions of the field .... we only see when photons are absorbed in our eye or camera.

Photons can interact with each other, but the probability is usually very small, unless the frequency &/or intensity is very high, or they're inside a nonlinear medium. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics

It probably isn't what you are thinking of, and it certainly isn't practical, but in principle there is a way to do it.
As PhysicsDave said, light beams intersect and keep going. When they emerge, they keep going as if the other beam wasn't there.
But they add in a complex way in the zone of intersection. You can see the same thing in water waves. There are crests and troughs. Where two crests meet, the wave is doubly tall. Where two troughs meet, it is doubly deep. Where a crest meets a trough, they cancel, and the height is zero.
Waves don't disappear in this process. There is just as much double size wave and zero size way. But they do rearrange where you find the wave. In principle, you could use this to arrange the zero size wave to be at the surface, and the double size wave to be elsewhere. This is the interference pattern that Google keeps trying to steer you to.
One problem with this is that visible and infrared waves have really tiny wavelengths. Millionths of an inch or less. So an interference pattern can only shift the dark spots a millionth of an inch or so.
To make this work, you would need to work with much longer wavelengths. Radio waves are light with long enough wavelengths. So your heater would be a high power radio transmitter.
A second problem is that for an interference pattern to last longer than it takes for one wave to go by, the two beams must have the same wavelength. The only practical way to achieve this is with an optical (or radar) beam splitter. The two halves of one beam can be recombined to form an interference pattern. So here is the second thing you are being steered to.
